# Flutter: The image is not centered within the circle

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having trouble aligning this image correctly within the circular avatar widget. It's automatically shifting to the top and doesn't fit inside the parent widget.

[image]

I want to position the image at the centre of the circle. This is the code I have.

```
Container(
   color: Colors.grey,
   height: 180,
   width: 180,
   child: ClipRRect(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
     child: Center(
      child: Image.file(
       File(model.profileImage!.path),
       height: 180,
       fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ),
```

Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: are you sure your code is like that? because i think that if you give the same heigth for the image and container it will display the image with the height same as the container, but from the image you give it looks like the image height is smaller then the container. I also have tried your code and it works well in me, the image can be display in the center of the circle

Comment: Why don't you use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html directly?

Comment: @KEZIAANGELINE This happens only with smaller images. Larger images fits perfectly.

Comment: @AfridiKayal The same happens with CircleAvatar. Works well with larger images and smaller images gets out of position.

Comment: can you share the image so i can try it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Hope this will help you, 

Container(
   color: Colors.grey,
   height: 180,
   width: 180,
   child: Center(
     child: ClipOval(
  child: SizedBox.fromSize(
    size: Size.fromRadius(100), // Image radius
    child: Image.network( 'https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg', fit: BoxFit.cover),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the above solution, but it's still the same result. This happens with smaller images and larger images fits perfectly.

Comment: can u share the image so we can fix it

Answer (score 0):

For any specific reason if you want it to be done with `Container` only then you can use `alignment` property of container, something like this it will make sure to centere the child of container irrespective of height and size of the child.

```
Container(
   alignment: Alignment.center, // Alignment property to center it's child
   color: Colors.grey,
   height: 180,
   width: 180,
   child: ClipRRect(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
     child: Center(
      child: Image.file(
       File(model.profileImage!.path),
       height: 180,
       fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ),
```

Else instead of using `container` for this, use `CircleAvatar` something like this,

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 150,
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imgUrl),
  // For asset image you can use AssetImage('asset path')
  // for file image you can use FileImage(file name)
),
```

by this the image will always be in the center no need to give height or anything, You can play with radius to adjust the circle's height.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i've tried your code with smaller image and yes i get not full center of the circle like this
[image]

then i tried to using BoxDecoration like the code below :

```
Container(
    height: 180,
    width: 180,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: NetworkImage(
                "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUYQL7GQdlcGan_WJEjhX0GtR8CfWXCtwFXJ1oASBioHDGkAhv"))),
  ),
```

it can display the image fit with the Container size you want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
   color: Colors.grey,
   height: 180,
   width: 180,
   child: ClipRRect(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
     child: Center(
      child: Image.network(
       "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUYQL7GQdlcGan_WJEjhX0GtR8CfWXCtwFXJ1oASBioHDGkAhv",
       height: 180,
       fit: BoxFit.fill, // BoxFit.cover to BoxFit.fill 
      ),
     ),
    ),
   )
```

BoxFit.fill will make your image fill the circle. I hope I have helped. Enjoy your work. Output:

[image]